# How to print without print dialog in java

Tags: java, netbeans, printing

I want to print something (i.e. number) in a textfield by hitting a button and prints it automatically. Im a student and i dont know java much. The bottomline is i wanna print programatically that i will set the printer in the program itself.

Please and thank you in advance.

```
private void printToPrinter(){
  String printData = jLabel1.getText();
  PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
  job.setPrintable(new OutputPrinter(printData));

  try 
  {
    job.print();
  }
  catch (PrinterException e)
  {
    // Print job did not complete.
  }   
}
```

im just trying a simple code first and my code above is either wrong or incomplete. Im using netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by KeyEvent class and by implementing KeyListener interface

```
 import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;

    public class FirstJava extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

        JTextField jtf = new JTextField();

        FirstJava() {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
            setVisible(true);
            jtf.addKeyListener(this);
            setSize(new Dimension(30, 20));
            add(jtf);
            pack();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new FirstJava();
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                //What you to do then
                System.out.println("Welcome");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }
    }
```